# How to use DTD ENTITY external reference in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml, log4j, dtd

I tried to use entities from external dtd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" 
[<!ENTITY logHome SYSTEM "log4j-entity.dtd">]
>
```

**log4j-entity.dtd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ENTITY logHome "/root/crm_test/">
```

I tried to use the entity values in attribute values like this.

```
<param name="File" value="&logHome;log/info.log"/>
```

I get this errror:

```
The external entity reference "&logHome;" is not permitted in an attribute value.
```

How can I do this?

**Note:**

This thing works..

```
<!ENTITY logHome  "/root/crm_test/">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the entity inside the internal subset a parameter entity and then reference it.

Change:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" 
[<!ENTITY logHome SYSTEM "log4j-entity.dtd">]
>
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % logHome SYSTEM "log4j-entity.dtd">
%logHome;
]>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML specs specifically forbid the use of external entities in attribute values. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#forbidden

> The following are forbidden, and constitute fatal errors: [...] a reference to an external entity in an attribute value.

So the answer is: XML won't let you do what you're trying to do. You might, however, get a similar effect if you ran your XML through an XSLT processor and applied transformations as needed.

Comment: I think the OP is referencing an external entity on accident. The entity he/she really wants to reference is not an external entity. This would possible in XML.

Comment: Ah yes, that would make sense indeed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong here.

1. You are using the entity name `logHome` for two different things (an external entity containing declarations, which should as Daniel Haley points out be a parameter entity) and an internal entity whose replacement text names a directory.
2. As a consequence, your reference to `&logHome;` in the attribute value is understood to be a reference to the resource whose URI is "`log4j-entity.dtd`".

The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to declare the `logHome` entity in the internal subset:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" [
<!ENTITY logHome "/root/crm_test/">
]>
```

If you really want the declaration of `logHome` to be external, it might be less confusing to use a different name for the parameter entity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" [
<!ENTITY % logHomeDeclaration SYSTEM "log4j-entity.dtd">
%logHomeDeclaration;
]>
```